# Detect post type attachment in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, attachment

In my website https://chicken-device.ir, I have many not find the page, after I change the permalink of a post.

Many of the not found pages are for images pages. I wrote some code to redirect url link e.g. `https://example.com/post-name` to `https://example.com/blog/post-name`.

Now I have many attachment files then return 404 page in google webmaster tools.
How can I detect post type attachment in WordPress? target only attachment file page.

Answer (score 0):

Post the code that redirects urls.
You can check post type with this code:

```
$queried_object = get_queried_object();
$post_type = $queried_object->post_type;
```